# Can you pass by reference in Java?

Tags: c#, java, parameters, pass-by-reference

Sorry if this sounds like a newbie question, but the other day a Java developer mentioned about passing a paramter by reference (by which it was ment just pass a Reference object)

From a C# perspective I can pass a reference type by value or by reference, this is also true to value types

I have written a noddie console application to show what i mean.. can i do this in Java?

```
namespace ByRefByVal
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Creating of the object
            Person p1 = new Person();
            p1.Name = "Dave";
            PrintIfObjectIsNull(p1); //should not be null

            //A copy of the Reference is made and sent to the method
            PrintUserNameByValue(p1);
            PrintIfObjectIsNull(p1);

            //the actual reference is passed to the method
            PrintUserNameByRef(ref p1);    //<-- I know im passing the Reference
            PrintIfObjectIsNull(p1);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void PrintIfObjectIsNull(Object o)
        {
            if (o == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("object is null");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("object still references something");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// this takes in a Reference type of Person, by value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="person"></param>
        private static void PrintUserNameByValue(Person person)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
            person = null; //<- this cannot affect the orginal reference, as it was passed in by value.
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// this takes in a Reference type of Person, by reference
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="person"></param>
        private static void PrintUserNameByRef(ref Person person)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
            person = null; //this has access to the orginonal reference, allowing us to alter it, either make it point to a different object or to nothing.
        }


    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If it java cannot do this, then its just passing a reference type by value? (is that fair to say)

Many thanks

Bones

Comment: The endless C# distinctions don't even exist in Java.  What's a "reference type" in Java?  A non-primitive type?  You can't pass non-primitive types by value -- they're always references.  Since the concepts don't really map between languages, what are you asking, exactly?

Comment: You can certainly pass non-primitive types by value. In fact, that's all Java does. All you have in Java are primitives and references, and both are passed by value.

Comment: From your example, I am really glad Java doesn't support this.  This opens all sorts of problems which don't happen in Java.

Comment: @Peter, was not the point, the thing that got me was the incorrect useage of the term "pass by reference". The Java Developer was talking about passing a reference object, by value. Pass by reference could cause issues, however it provides solutions which could be applied (Look at the Swap code d. linked to). Note in the .Net Syntax, both sides (method and the caller) will know its by reference, as a developer you should then ask yourself why you need this. thus you are still responcible for developing and testing your code.

Comment: Note that you can set person.Name = null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, Java cannot do this. Java only passes by value. It passes references by value too.

Comment: +1 For "It passes references by value." The most accurate things around here.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I'm just learning JAVA with Eclipse for a few days now on my spare time, if I may say so. That is an important language feature you say here.

Answer (score 10):

Pass by reference is a concept often misunderstood by Java devs, probably because they cannot do it. Read this:

http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: how do we implement the swap function in java.

Comment: swap cannot be implemented in java, as all parameters are always passed by value. if you want to swap two values, you have to do it within the scope of your method; you will not be able to refactor that to a method of its own. workarounds such as JRL's may be possible, but not really doing what you want, here

Answer (score 1):

> From a C# perspective I can pass a
>   reference type by value or by
>   reference, this is also true to value
>   types

It's relatively misleading to say "pass a reference type by value" in C#.

You cannot pass a reference type by value - you can pass a *reference to the object*, or a *reference to the reference*. In java, you cannot pass a reference to the reference.

Your noddie application makes the distinction a little clearer, however.

Comment: i agree with your distiction

Answer (score 1):

Technically, as we know, variables that reference objects are strictly pointers to the object. When passing an object as a parameter to a method, the pointer or reference gets copied to the parameter variable. Java calls this "pass by value".

So, you end up with at least two variables that reference the same object. If you set the parameter variable to null, other variables keep their value thanks to reference counting.

If you have the following method:

```
public void function(Person person) {};
```

And an object:

```
Person marcus = new Person();
marcus.name = "Marcus";
```

Calling the method like this:

```
function(marcus);
```

You basically get this in the method's local scope:

```
Person person = marcus;
```

If you set `person = null`, it doesn't affect the value of `marcus`. This is due to reference counting.

However, if you do this:

```
person.name = null;
```

This is also true:

```
marcus.name == null;
```

You do have a reference to the original object in the parameter variable. Affecting the parameter variable does affect the original object. You can do everything except set it to null and expect the original to be set to null also. Reference counting prevents that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you pointed out, Java is passing references by value. This makes a good interview topic for java programmers, most seem to get it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can do is pass AtomicReference.  This can be altered by the caller.  It is rather ugly, but IMHO it should be.  Changing an argument in a method is a bad idea.